# no module name 'django'(already installed django)

Tags: python, django

I get this error when I run "python3 manage.py runserver"

```
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

but I already installed and activated django in the virtual environment...

I really don't know how to fix it because it worked well before

Comment: This almost certainly means that `python3 manage.py runserver` does not cause the same installation of Python to run as the one where you installed Django. It is not possible to tell you more than this without seeing the details of how your system is set up. You should try to diagnose the problem yourself by checking e.g. `which python3` and `python3 -m pip list`.

Comment: It is a good habit to use `python3 -m pip` (or `python -m pip`, on systems configured appropriately) to run pip, rather than just `pip`. This will ensure that you use the `pip` that matches the Python you will get with `python3`/`python` by itself, whether or not a virtual environment is active. (On Windows, it is also *necessary* when upgrading pip, because Windows doesn't like when a program tries to replace its own file on disk).